# ASP.NET MVC Razor - Click on a DropDownList to redirect to another view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new in ASP.NET MVC, please excuse me if my question is too simple. I have an ASP.NET MVC DropDownList in razor:

```
 @{var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>
         {
          new SelectListItem { Text = "Patient List", Value="Patient List" },
          new SelectListItem { Text = "Benchmarking", Value="Benchmarking" },
          new SelectListItem { Text = "Center Specific", Value="Center Specific" },
          new SelectListItem { Text = "ECMO Run", Value="ECMO Run" }
         };
        }
        @Html.DropDownList("Reports",new SelectList(listItems,"Value","Text"))
```

If the customer clicks on the one of list items, I will call corresponding .cshtml (another view). How to implement this? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Bad idea (that is not the expected behavior), but you need javascript to handle client side events, and your `SelectListItem` will need to contain the url you want to redirect to.

Comment: Try to populate your SelectListItem in controller first , then what @StephenMuecke suggested , use javascript to handle the changes.

Comment: Thank you both. Could you please write a code example?

Comment: I doubt anyone will help you write bad code for a bad design. Just use 4 `@Html.ActionLink()` to generate the 4 links in your page (and creating an second identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one using `new SelectList()` is just pointless)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jquery

```
$("#Reports").click(function(){
var selectedValue=    $(this).find('option:selected').val();
if(selectedValue.toLowerCase()=="patient list")
{
 location.href="your link";
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I just have used toLowerCase() function instead of toLower().

Answer (score 1):

In this example you can load partial view depends on selected item, I believe it's more friendly approach then redirect.

```
$('#list').on('change', function() {
             var selectedView = $(this).val();
             $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: @Url.Action("Method","Controller"),
                    data: { viewName: selectedView  },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (content) {
                        $("#newContent").html(content);
                    },
                    error: function () {

                    }
                });      
});
```

Comment: "change" method will not hit if your selected value does not change.